# Determining user language based on IP address (geolocation)

Tags: php, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I've integrated two pieces of PHP code found on different websites. The first part of code finds out what country you are in and the second one determines the language.  I have tried running it but with no luck.  It does not give me a error, just a blank white screen.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

function visitor_country()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result  = "Unknown";
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));

    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
    {
        $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
    }

    return $result;
}

    session_start();
    header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

    if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
            $lang = $_GET['lang'];

            // register the session and set the cookie
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

            setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    } else if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
            $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    } else if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
            $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    } else {
            $lang = 'en';
    }

    switch ($lang) {
            case 'en':
            $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
            break;

            case 'de':
            $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
            break;

            if(visitor_country() == "Germany") {
                default:
                $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
                echo "Germany";
            } else {
                default:
                $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
                echo "Not in Germany";
            }

    }

    include_once 'languages/' . $lang_file;



?>
```

I could not include the language code, but rest assured it works as I use it on my site without auto-country detection.

Comment: Blank white page most of the time indicates a server error. Do you have access to your server logs?

Comment: No errors in PHP error log, Maybe its the code?

Comment: Don't use those error suppressing `@`s!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code returns an error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'default' (T_DEFAULT) in yourfile.php on line`. It means that you're misusing `default` in [`switch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement. Replace your last part of your code with this:

```
default:
  if(visitor_country() == "Germany") {
     $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
     echo "Germany";
  } else {
     $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
     echo "Not in Germany";
  }
```

Take out `default` from inside of `if/else` statement.

#### EDIT 1:

Make sure that PHP displays `ERRORS`, `WARNING` and `NOTICES`  to properly debug your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1);
```

#### EDIT 2:

If it was working without the `switch` statement, like you said, then you must make sure that files `lang.en.php`/`lang.de.php` really exist.

#### EDIT 3:

You are suppressing errors with having `@` in-front of `json_decode(file_get_contents`. Most likely you would have to edit your `php.ini` and enable `allow_url_fopen` to make it work. I bet if you remove `@`, you will get an error:

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in
```

I wouldn't strongly recommend using this kind of method to detect user language and enabling `allow_url_fopen` as it's possible security flaw! In case you're interested, I will provide you with much better solution for determining user browsers' language.

Comment: Just got it to work, had to remove default.  Guess i didnt see that.  Thanks

Comment: No, you, must keep the `switch`. Let me update my answer with full example online.

Comment: You must keep switch and just delete one of the `default`, that is on the inside of `if/else` and put it right above it. Example: http://codepad.org/Nq6Np3X2

Comment: It now doesnt work, it was working without the switch.  Suggestions? (Im using your code)

Comment: @HrachGhapantsyan Look at my edit 1 and tell me what error do you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40464/discussion-between-hrach-ghapantsyan-and-ilia-rostovtsev)