# Display website in a user's native language based on the IP address

Tags: json, geolocation, ip, ip-geolocation

I want my website to be opened in a visitor's native language as determined by the IP address where the user has logged in from.

By default the page opens in English, but I want my customers from France to read the site in French. I have gone through [www.ipinfo.io](http://www.ipinfo.io/) for information, but I am still a bit confused and would like to know the json format.

Comment: Possible duplicates?: *[Determining user language based on IP address (geolocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19755290/3357935)* and *[Website that recognizes user's location/IP & changes lang. based on that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2039016/3357935)*

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `accept-language` header that the user's browser passes to your site to determine the language, rather than the user's current country.

If you do want to customize the site content based on the country the http://ipinfo.io code you'd use would look something like this:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    if(response.country == 'US') {
        // User is in the USA
    } else {
        // User is elsewhere 
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

You can find a full mapping of country codes to things like names, currency codes, dialing codes and more at http://country.io/data/

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using the IP alone to determine the display language.
Using the Accept-Language header is far more reliable.

Consider the following relatively common scenario:
An only-English-speaking person travels to Russia and opens your website. Then the Russian landing page is displayed in Cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your last question, but it is a better solution to your problem.

Rather than using an IP address to determine locale, use localization based on the browser's "Accept-Language" header. This header is typically set by default when installing a browser based on your operating system's localization settings.

Most modern UI frameworks (be it web, mobile, or desktop) have localization/internationalization libraries.